# deprecated errors while setting up Built2Go Car Dealer on xampp

Tags: php

hi everyone i'm trying to set up Built2Go Car Dealer on my website and even tho i have followed all the instructions correctly to setup config.php ... i keep receiving the following errors on index.php when trying to install Built2Go Car Dealer ... how do i resolve them?

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\install.php on line 185

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\admincp\func.php on line 434

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\admincp\system_cls.php on line 171

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\admincp\system_cls.php on line 173

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\admincp\system_cls.php on line 152

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\admincp\system_cls.php on line 177

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\admincp\func.php on line 447
```

any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Deprecated" warnings mean that the language (PHP) has moved on and does not recommend using certain functions or functionality anymore. In fact, anything that's marked as deprecated now will almost certainly be removed completely in a near future update.

This means that the software has been out of touch with the development of PHP for a while and hasn't updated to the newest coding standards. This is something that will need to be addressed by the author, or the software will/may stop working on newer versions of PHP. For now you can suppress these messages using [`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), but **that's not a long-term solution**.

Answer (score 2):

These features are deprecated in PHP 5.26+ and will eventually be removed completely.  `eregi()` is being replaced by `preg_match()`.  Unless you intend to modify the source code of this application, you'll have to live with the deprecation warnings.

If the errors are displaying on screen, rather than in your error log, you should be turning `display_errors = off` in `php.ini` for a production system.  To prevent the deprecation errors from showing anywhere, even the log, use `error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED`

Comment: More accurately, the entire ereg family of functions is deprecated and should be switched over to preg equivalents.