# ereg function in php

Tags: php, regex, ereg

When I write this code :

```
$pat='^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*@[a-zA-z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$';
$mail='javad.y1';
ereg($pat,$mail);
```

I'm getting this error :

> Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\Test\test.php on line 10

Comment: Because `ereg` is **deprecated**. See [deprecated errors while setting up Built2Go Car Dealer on xampp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227657/deprecated-errors-while-setting-up-built2go-car-dealer-on-xampp), then [http://php.net/ereg](http://php.net/ereg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement "**Error : Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated**" pretty much answers the question for you.

In terms of using the more modern equivalent, see the [Differences from POSIX regex page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) in the PHP manual and the [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function you'll need to use going forward.

Alternatively, for some exciting further reading why not check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecated

**UPDATED WITH SAMPLE CODE**

If you're attempting to validate an email, then you could use:

```
if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*@[a-zA-z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+/", $email)) {
    // The email is valid. Yay for stuff! And things!
}
```

That said, I wouldn't say this is necessarily the best approach.

Comment: Can you write this code and use preg_match instead of ereg function ?

Comment: @Javad I've updated my answer with the relevant `preg_match` equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`ereg()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) is deprecated. You should use [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead.

Comment: Can you write this code and use preg_match instead of ereg function ?

Comment: @Javad: What? Seriously? Just replace `ereg` with `preg_replace`.

Comment: But I'm getting this error : `preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\wamp\www\Test\test.php on line 10 `

Answer (score 0):

You now youe [Perl-compatible RegEx](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) instead.

[POSIX RegEx](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.regex.php):

> ```
> As of PHP 5.3.0 this extension is deprecated,  calling any function
> ```
>
> provided by this extension  will issue
>   an E_DEPRECATED notice.